# removing warnings caused by custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, warnings

I am getting the following warnings in the code:
[image]

Should I just remove all of these methods in the code or what?

```
#import "ReservationCell.h"


@implementation ReservationCell
@synthesize origin;
@synthesize destination;
@synthesize time_range;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [origin release];
        [destination release];
        [time_range release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    @end
```

Also I am getting this final linker warning, anyone know how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All of those warnings are for UIViewController methods. A UITableViewCell is a UIView, so it would not respond wo any of those.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: how about that linker warning?

Comment: does /Developer/SmarTrek/RestKit/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator exist? It looks like a non standard directory. Are you including any special libraries?

Comment: Non standard in the sense of not being standard for iphone development.